# Why are my colours blending like this in Photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, color, transparency, brush, blending

I've been using Photoshop for about a year for digital art and design for various projects. However, there is one problem with the colours.

Every time I paint using a dark colour on the canvas and then a light colour over it, it makes the light colour neon. To make things worse, if I paint directly on the background layer, the colours become lighter despite my opacity being 100% on the layers, the brushes, etc.

To stop this from happening, I've been creating new layers every colour but that makes it exceptionally difficult to blend. Is there something obvious I'm missing?

[image: Top line: colour on Background, Bottom line: colour on New Layer]

[image: Pastel colours on black turning neon]

[image: Pastel blue and yellow interacting strangely on the same layer]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure the blending mode is set to `Normal` on the brush settings.

Different blending modes will affect the way your strokes are overlapping, precisely what's happening in your images.

[image]

Comment: That worked! Thank you so much!